# How to remove the square brackets at the beginning and end of the special characters String?

Tags: java, special-characters

Below is the example where I want to remove the square brackets using Java :-

```
String specialCharacters = "[!& *=~}[]"
String specialCharactes1 = "[[[&%*@#(#][[]"
```

I want the result like this respectively :-

> !& *=~}[
>
> [[&%*@#(#][[

That Means I want to remove only one square brackets from both the ends. I saw many solutions but those were related to JavaScript.

This can be done using regex but I am not sure How I can replicate this.

Comment: `System.out.println(specialCharacters.replaceAll("\\[(.+)\\]", "$1"));` and `System.out.println(specialCharactes1.replaceAll("\\[(.+)\\]", "$1"));`

Comment: Do all strings you are considering have matching square brackets at the start and end? Do some only have one? Do some strings not even have the brackets?

Comment: Every String would have square brackets at the beginning and the end.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - I used the same code.. It was just the inverted commas issue. Thanks anyway,

Comment: You can also use `specialCharacters.substring(1, specialCharacters.length()-1)` if all the strings start with '[' and end with ']'.

Answer (score -2):

```
String specialCharacters = "[!& *=~}[]";
if(null!=specialCharacters)
{
   String answer = specialCharacters.substring(specialCharacters.indexOf(" 
                    [")+1,specialCharacters.indexOf("]"));
}
```

This will work if there is only one [ and ] in the input string